# Is there any security recommendation for laravel? Database got hacked

Tags: mysql, laravel, security

My Laravel database got hacked for the second time. the hacker deleted all tables and left a table threatening to delete it If I didn't send bitcoin. That's not a problem since I do have a backup but what can I do to prevent it?

This is for Laravel 6. the first time I had debugging mode ON in the .env file so I thought this might be the problem. after turning debugging off I still got hacked am I missing anything?

Comment: From here we cannot say what exactly is your vulnerability. There is too many things to be considered. You can start by checking if your queries are not raw, Laravel was installed right (not site.com/public as some beginners do), your database is not exposed to the entire internet, there are no XSS attacks possible, lat but not least you changed your password right?

Comment: yeah I sure did change my password after each attack. can you link me any helpful links to these vulnerabilities I might have?

Comment: Probably the vulnerability used was not the Laravel itself, but your server. Tell us more about where is your Laravel hosted, versions of everything...

Comment: Please specify where your app is hosted, which versions of linux, php, apache/nginx, mysql you are using and your general setup (eg. is the mysql hosted on same machine on localhost?). If using either apache or nginx please show the config files

Comment: Is it hosting or virtual server ?

Comment: Don't forget to run `composer install --no-dev` instead of just `composer install` on your public server. Whoops exposes the server credentials, and this is most likely the way the hacker retrieved your database credentials.

Comment: Which is why you shouldn't use Laravel in the first place...

Answer (score 0):

Hello Mohamed Elmoniry,

I would check your server database configuration for the following security settings I mean this is pretty basic and normally done automatically if you are not self hosting and using a service like forge or digital ocean, but here you go:

---

1. Update the password plugin
2. Change the root password
3. Remove anonymous users
4. Disallow remote root login
5. Remove test database

*If you are new to this and you are using MYSQL on your server you can run the following command/script that will automatically guide you through that process*

---

```
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

**Additionally:**

If you are using a web server I would also enable SSH and deactivate password login.

If you are using a firewall I would check that only the necessary ports to your application are allowed by the UTM (Unified threat management) if it is a hardware firewall. (same applies to a software firewall)

Answer (score 0):

It would be great if you know how the hacker got into the database. Maybe you have an old database version? Maybe you have an easy-to-crack password and have exposed your database to the internet. Laravel by default blocks SQL injection, so that can't be it.

If you have exposed your database, a good first step is to block all requests and allow only ones from certain IP addresses, like your server and IP addresses where you often work. This way, hackers can only get to your database if they are on one of those IP's.

Do you publish your code to GitHub? Maybe the hacker got the password from your repository (this is only possible if this is public). You should make sure you NEVER EVER publish your .env file to the internet and only keep local copies.

But the best solution would be to find out how he got in. Then you can block that entrance. You should certainly check your database version and update it if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

it seems your website has some shell (malware) stored. Virus take palace with following reasons :

1. Old version framework (but you are using v6, that is updated)
2. A shell/virus already in code (check if a php shell exist, & scan with antivirus)
3. You have public git repo, where attacker placed his malware
4. You have credentials hardcoded that leaked, either through git repo or JS files.
5. You have unrestricted file upload option in your code, which allow hacker to upload shell.
6. your database server is publicly exposed,allowing anyone to access.
7. If you are using older jenkins or other automation tool, which exploit used.
8. SQL injection, (check logs)

Thanks, 
Jaikey

Answer (score 0):

Check whether your .env or .env.sample files expose to public for some reason?

https://yourdomain.com/system/.env

If yes, block the public access of .env by adding the code below to the .htaccess file.

```
<FilesMatch "^\.env">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```